# How to save user login by firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sencha-touch

I want to save user login credential, The app is build using SenchaTouch, and the database - using firebase. The browser automatically saves the information but does not have access to it (I tried to save cookies but the password is encrypted),
I know that Firebase has a function that causes the device to remember this (this does not mean keeping Firebase's DataBase...), this will save  use from login process every time he uses the app, but I did not find it and did not understand how I use it,

Any kind of help will be appreciated.(code, idea or explanation)

Thanks

sorry for bad English ;)

Comment: So you want to save user login credentials (email, password) on Firebase ? On the user device ?

Comment: On the user device,

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Shared preferences** to store and get user login credentials on the user device. Here is the official Android documentation : [Saving key value sets](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)